# How to group emails from google sheets with javascript

Tags: javascript

Situation: This is a Leave (or time off) approval/monitoring system for a small office of around 40 people. They put in for leave via google forms which is fed (eventually) into a google sheet. Once a month, we need to send out a single email to each person who took leave containing every entry they made for the month. I have altered the standard javascript from google that will send an email from a spreadsheet but it sends one email per row. I need to send a consolidated email to each person. Prior to running the script, the spreadsheet will only contain records with applicable dates, and will be sorted by [Email] and [Start Date] columns so there is no need to do any of that work in this script.

Here are the all columns in order: Timestamp, Email, Type of Leave Requested, Starting Date, Last Date, Number of Hours, Optional Note, Approval Decision, Optional Explanation.

I've tried creating a 2D array but my previous attempts at such an array have only resulted in using my 100/day google transactions in a matter of seconds. :/  Help is appreciated.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var menu = [{
    name: "Send Email",
    functionName: "uiSendEmail"
  }];

  ss.addMenu("Send Email Test", menu);
}

function uiSendEmail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();

  range= range.offset(1, 0, range.getNumRows()-1);
  range.getValues().forEach( function( cell, key, data ){


    var body = "Type of Leave - " + cell[2] + "\n\nStarting - " + cell[3] + "\n\nEnding - " + cell[4] + "\n\nHours - " + cell[5] + "\n\nNote Provided - " + cell[6] + "\n\n\n";
    //   "Type of Leave " + cell[2] \n\n;+ "Starting " + cell[3] \n\n + "Ending " + cell[4] \n\n + "Hours " + cell[5] \n\n + "Note provided " + cell[6] 
    GmailApp.sendEmail(cell[1], "Recent Requests for Time Off", body);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an object, loop through the values and add them to the corresponding email.

```
function uiSendEmail() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getDataRange();
var emails = {};

range= range.offset(1, 0, range.getNumRows()-1);
range.getValues().forEach( function( cell, key, data ){

    var body = "Type of Leave - " + cell[2] + "\n\nStarting - " + cell[3] + "\n\nEnding - " + cell[4] + "\n\nHours - " + cell[5] + "\n\nNote Provided - " + cell[6] + "\n\n\n";

    if(typeof emails[cell[1]] === 'undefined'){ 
      emails[cell[1]] = body;
    } else {
      emails[cell[1]] += body;
    }
   });

//Now loop through the email object and send each completed one
for(var address in emails) {
   GmailApp.sendEmail(address, "Recent Requests for Time Off", emails[address]);
}
```

Comment: Max G.,
PERFECT!  Well done. Simple solution to a long-time problem. 

Much Thanks,
usmids

Comment: My pleasure! :)